# How can I make the label's text appear next to the toggle when the toggle itself uses the label for its styling

Tags: html, css

I've written a small toggle component which can be used in place of a checkbox.

The way it works is that the label element itself is the toggle, meaning that it should be accessible and work if either the toggle or label is clicked.

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the text to appear next to the slider as adding padding or any sort of margin distorts the slider skin.

The live demo is here: https://svelte.dev/repl/84cfc5281b5d4289b99b222b338f48ae?version=3.20.1

The code consists of the following CSS:

```
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
  }

  .switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }

  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 34px;
  }

  .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196f3;
  }

  input:checked + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196f3;
  }

  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
  }
```

and the following html:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" bind:checked />
  <span class="slider" />
  <span>Accept Terms</span>
</label>
```

Obviously the easy fix is to move the text out of the label, but then I lose in accessibility, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Since the switch element has `position: relative` and the `slider` has a fixed widht, you can add `position: absolute` to the `<span>` with text.

```
.slider + span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
}
```

Then you can position it as you want.
You can also use `white-space: nowrap` to make the text on one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by positioning the text span as absolute:

```
span:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: calc(100% + 10px);
    top: 6px
}
```